# ASP SQL Server query question

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am new to ASP. I've been coding with PHP for about 10 years now but just started ASP.

Here is my code:

```
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
strStoredProcedure = "SP_AddHPOrderItem'" & empIdent & "'" 
rs.Open strStoredProcedure,strConnect, adopenForwardOnly, adlockoptimistic, adcmdtext
```

I am assuming that the variable `RS("styleDesc")` is coming from this query as I have found no reference to an `RS`, only `rs`. Not sure if variables are case sensitive in ASP.

My question is, is `strStoredProcedure` a function? Because I don't understand how this query can be made with the variable assigned the way it is.

How does `SP_AddHPOrderItem'" & empIdent & "'` constitute a query? There are no selects, inserts, updates, or anything like that.

If an expert could point me in the right direction if would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are starting asp, and not perhaps asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement of a SQL batch can be a stored procedure name; if so, SQL Server will execute it even if it's not prefixed with `exec`.  So the net effect is if you send this to SQL Server:

```
exec SP_AddHPOrderItem 'empIdent'
```